# Deploying rails app on heroku, not displaying SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, database-connection

can you help me with this problem?

I cannot execute "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL")" on production version (deployed on Heroku), although it works locally.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Games</th>
  <th>Wins</th>
  <th>Win Ratio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
select * from players").each_with_index do |performer, i| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= (i+1) %> </td>
    <td><%= performer[0] %> </td>
    <td><%= performer[1] %></td>
    <td><%= performer[2] %></td>
    <th><%= performer[3] %> <%='%'%></th>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

DEVELOPMENT
[image]
PRODUCTION
[image]
HEROKU LOGS
[image]

Comment: Does the `players` table in production has any records?

Comment: yes, there are records. All other data are displayed also on production version. Just this SQL query execution is missing.

Comment: Ok. What is the server log tells you for this? Can you post it in the question?

Comment: I added "heroku logs" to the question description.

Comment: Are you using Postgres in development too?
Is it that you have players table in your database with fields for name, games, wins & win ratio?

Comment: No, I use Sqlite3 in development, PG in production. Well I have prepared different query to actually put there, but for clarity I inserted here this easy one. It should not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment (sorry no rep yet)

Since you are calling all players why not do something like

```
<% @players.each do |p| %>
<td><%= (i+1) %> </td> 
<td><%= p.name %> </td>
<td><%= p.games %></td> 
<td><%= p.wins %></td> 
<% percent = p.wins / p.games %>
<% percent = percent * 100 %>
<% percent = number_with_precision(percent, :precision => 0) %>
<th><%= percent %> %</th>
<% end %>
```

In controller do something like @players = Player.all

This will remove the need for any SQL statement in your view, removing the problem of having pg and sql